# Why using putExtra() instead of direct property invocation?

Tags: java, android

When we need to pass data to other activities in android, we use putExtra().
My question is why we do this instead of declaring public properties and access it as we do in Java and other programming language when we are developing desktop or we applications, what is the pros of this, or this approach was chosen because of some limitations?

Comment: those who down voted, why? or just it is a habit?

Comment: probably because you did no research yourself before asking

Comment: I spent 2 hours but did not find a good answer until  you @VladyslavMatviienko answered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `as we do in Java` android is using Java.
2. `instead of declaring public properties and access it` That is done because you should not have an instance of an activity anywhere except this activity. You should not create instances of any activity on your own using constructors. Only system should create activities. What you should do is to *ask the system to create it* (using `startActivity()`). That is done because if you have an instance of activity anywhere, this will result in memory leak.

You should develop you app the way that it doesn't need to access methods or fields of other activities.

Comment: Thank you, regarding point 1 I said (when we are developing desktop or web applications) I know android is using java, but in web and desktop we use constructors and properties not putExtra(). This is my point